# copy directory structure without files

Tags: bash, find

Hello i am trying to make a script which takes two arguments (names of directories) and copies the structure of the first into the other.

This is my code:

```
cd $1 && find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /$2/{} \;
```

when i run the script i dont get any errors but nothing happens. What am i doing wrong please help thank you.

edit: the script is saved in home and both directories are also in home (~). i run the script in terminal:

```
sudo bash DN1c.sh dir1 dir2
```

first directory has multiple subdirectories and the second directory is empty

Comment: We need more information. How you run the script (what is the command)? What is the directory structure of `$1`? Edit your question to include that, no comment.

Comment: thanks i edited the question

Comment: a) you should probably remove the slash before "$2".  b) your script will possibly also recurse into "$2", and try to copy that into "$2"....  c) why do you use `sudo`?

Comment: i removed the slash and nothin changed. i use sudo because i get permission denied when i use it without

Comment: It's strange you get permission denied on directories in your own $HOME (~) directory.

Comment: As an aside, I'd put double quotes around `$1` and `$2` in your script.

Comment: i put the quotes but i am still trying to stop the recursion

Comment: If $1 is not in the $2 tree, recursion probably won't happen.  What is the actual output you get when you run the script?

Comment: it keeps making folders inside dir2 until i force it to stop

Comment: @rerboi check dir1, you've probably created dir2/dir2/dir2/dir2/dir2/dir2.... in it

Comment: Oh, and also if you ran this with sudo, you probably have a dir2 in root dir (/) as well

Comment: yes that did happen i want to fix this and i dont know how

Comment: Have you considered using [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for something like this? Even though used for network copies, it shines with local disk->disk copies too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export src=$1/. dest=$2
find "$src" -type d -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\0" "${@//"$src"/"$dest"}"' sh {} + | xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to copy files and/or directories.

To copy directories only, set `--max-size=0` and no files will be copied.

Example:

```
rsync -r -n -v --max-size=0 src_path/ dest_path

       ^                                        recursive
          ^                                     dry run - nothing copied
             ^                                  verbose
                     ^                          no files
                              ^                 src path
                                    ^           use a trailing / if you don't 
                                                want the src_path created
                                                at dest
                                           ^    dest path
```